# Why does JS alert execute before console.log when a loop is following the statements

Tags: javascript

I have a JS code snippet which I use to introduce pause between calls being made. The snippet is:

```
function intPause(_wg_time_msec) {
    var _wg_now = new Date();
    var _wg_expire = _wg_now.getTime() + _wg_time_msec;
    while(_wg_now.getTime() < _wg_expire)
        _wg_now = new Date();
}
```

Now what I see is that if add an alert to this function before the while loop, it shows the alert instantly and then runs the while loop, but if I add a console.log instead of alert, console.log echoes the data after while loop completes. Can someone please help me in understanding this behavior and how can I get a better way to introduce pause between calls.

Comment: That's a really terrible thing to do to people visiting your web site. You're basically loading their CPU down with that code, and it's likely to result in a "slow script" warning from the browser. Use `setTimeout()` instead.

Comment: Oh and `console.log()` is different than `alert()` in that it's not necessarily synchronous. That's just the way it was implemented.

Comment: what are the calls you are trying to make?  why do you need to pause between them?

Comment: @Pointy: I know this code is terrible, but I have a specific need where setTimeout does not solve the issue.

Comment: @Jason: I have to introduce a delay so that the Ajax calls I have sent are completed before the other events are fired.

Comment: @Pointy: actually, the main use case is that we need to send a few AJAX calls before page unloads. We use pause to allow enough time (usually less than 500ms) to ensure calls register before page unloads. It works in Chrome, IE, but not in Firefox. Any ideas? Or any other alternative approaches you know?

Comment: @AnkitJain Figure out something different; you're going to spike the CPU :(

Comment: @AnkitJain What kind of specific need requires this kind of code?

Comment: You can't guarantee that you'll be able to complete anything when the user leaves a page; they might pull the power cord out from the computer, for example. In my experience a situation like that is evidence of some basic design flaw.

Comment: @Pointy: We can surely leave corner cases where the data is not available, but certainly an optimal solution must exist to the delay problem.

Comment: @Amaan: The need is as specified by Paras, need to have a delay after the Ajax calls are sent. The thing is that, if presence of alert makes it work fine, than why not some other event which can just execute in background and let other calls which were sent before the call to this function execute.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery you can temporarily set ajax calls to be synchronous:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ "async": false });
// make synchornous ajax call
var jqHxr = $.get(....)
$.ajaxSetup({"async": true});
```

Comment: i can even turn the ajax calls to be sync when I am making the call, but the point is I don't want it to get stuck if the server does not respond withing a given time. I think, adding an error timeout in the Ajax call be useful instead. Any suggestions with that?

Comment: you probably should read the jquery.ajax api (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) -- there is a timeout setting for ajax methods that can be overridden the same way (i.e. $.ajaxSetup( {"timeout": 1000});).  If the request times out, the error function will get called.

Comment: that is what I was saying, I would have to change my Ajax calls to do so. But I would like to do that as the last thing, also would the Sync call delay the page unloading event?

Comment: you don't need to add a timeout, it's built into jquery.  are you talking about asp.net's page unload?

Comment: a webpage unload event if a link is clicked on a page.

Comment: that would be a browser implementation, but i imagine most browsers would navigate away from a page regardless of whether there are outstanding ajax requests

Comment: yeah that is the precise reason I had to use the pause function.